# Can navigation drawer be set behind the content?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to set the main content frame on top of the navigation frame, making the content slide together with navigation tab?

Comment: you mean the drawer? like a Push -- http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel/

Answer (score 0):

I think [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) does what you are looking for.

Check out [its demo on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example) to see how it works.

Comment: i know, but i was looking for a native solution with android's DrawerLayout

Comment: I don't think that's possible.